Problem with animating model nodes in OpenGL
I have a helicopter 3D model. I'm trying to write a code for it in C++ using assimp so that only some of its nodes are animated/moving (namely, the ones with the names "main_rotor" and "rear_rotor".
This is the Model class that I have:
#include "Model.h"

#ifndef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#include <iostream>
#endif

Model::Model(string const& path, bool bSmoothNormals, bool gamma) : gammaCorrection(gamma)
{
    loadModel(path, bSmoothNormals);
}

void Model::Draw(Shader& shader)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < meshes.size(); i++)
    {
        // Check if the mesh corresponds to a node with a custom transformation
        if (isAnimated)
        {
            auto it = nodeTransforms.find(meshes[i].name);
            if (it != nodeTransforms.end())
            {
                // Apply the transformation for this node
                shader.setMat4("model", it->second); // Assuming the shader has a "model" uniform
            }
            else
            {
                // Use the identity matrix if no transformation exists
                shader.setMat4("model", glm::mat4(1.0f));
            }
        }
        meshes[i].Draw(shader);
    }
}

void Model::printNodeNames()
{
    for (const auto& name : nodeNames)
    {
        cout << "Collected Node: " << name << endl;
    }
}

void Model::SetRootTransf(glm::mat4 transform)
{
    if (!nodeNames.empty())
    {
        const std::string& rootNodeName = nodeNames[0]; // Assuming the root node is at index 0
        nodeTransforms[rootNodeName] = transform;
        std::cout << "Root transformation for node \"" << rootNodeName << "\" has been set.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: No nodes found. Unable to set root transformation.\n";
    }
}

void Model::setNodeTransforms(std::string st, glm::mat4 mat)
{
    nodeTransforms[st] = mat;
}

void Model::setIsAnimated(bool animated)
{
    isAnimated = animated;
}

void Model::moveModel(glm::mat4 transform)
{
    for (auto& mesh : meshes) {
        nodeTransforms[mesh.name] = transform;
    }
}

void Model::loadModel(string const& path, bool bSmoothNormals)
{
    // read file via ASSIMP
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | (bSmoothNormals ? aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals : aiProcess_GenNormals) | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace);
    // check for errors
    if (!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) // if is Not Zero
    {
        cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP:: " << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
        return;
    }
    // retrieve the directory path of the filepath
    directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of("\\"));

    // process ASSIMP's root node recursively
    processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);
}

void Model::processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene)
{
    // Print the current node's name
    cout << "Node Name: " << node->mName.C_Str() << endl << endl;

    // process each mesh located at the current node
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
    {
        // the node object only contains indices to index the actual objects in the scene. 
        // the scene contains all the data, node is just to keep stuff organized (like relations between nodes).
        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        //std::cout << mesh->mName << "\n";
        meshes.push_back(processMesh(node->mName.C_Str(), mesh, scene));
    }
    // after we've processed all of the meshes (if any) we then recursively process each of the children nodes
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
    {
        processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
    }

}

Mesh Model::processMesh(std::string nodeName, aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene)
{
    // data to fill
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vector<unsigned int> indices;
    vector<Texture> textures;

    // walk through each of the mesh's vertices
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
    {
        Vertex vertex;
        glm::vec3 vector; // we declare a placeholder vector since assimp uses its own vector class that doesn't directly convert to glm's vec3 class so we transfer the data to this placeholder glm::vec3 first.
        // positions
        vector.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
        vector.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
        vector.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
        vertex.Position = vector;
        // normals
        if (mesh->HasNormals())
        {
            vector.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
            vertex.Normal = vector;
        }
        else {
           int j = 0;
        }
        // texture coordinates
        if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0]) // does the mesh contain texture coordinates?
        {
            glm::vec2 vec;
            // a vertex can contain up to 8 different texture coordinates. We thus make the assumption that we won't 
            // use models where a vertex can have multiple texture coordinates so we always take the first set (0).
            vec.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
            vec.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
            vertex.TexCoords = vec;
            // tangent
            vector.x = mesh->mTangents[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mTangents[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mTangents[i].z;
            vertex.Tangent = vector;
            // bitangent
            vector.x = mesh->mBitangents[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mBitangents[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mBitangents[i].z;
            vertex.Bitangent = vector;
        }
        else
            vertex.TexCoords = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);

        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }
    // now wak through each of the mesh's faces (a face is a mesh its triangle) and retrieve the corresponding vertex indices.
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
        // retrieve all indices of the face and store them in the indices vector
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
    }
    // process materials
    aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
    // we assume a convention for sampler names in the shaders. Each diffuse texture should be named
    // as 'texture_diffuseN' where N is a sequential number ranging from 1 to MAX_SAMPLER_NUMBER. 
    // Same applies to other texture as the following list summarizes:
    // diffuse: texture_diffuseN
    // specular: texture_specularN
    // normal: texture_normalN

    // 1. diffuse maps
    vector<Texture> diffuseMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse");
    textures.insert(textures.end(), diffuseMaps.begin(), diffuseMaps.end());
    // 2. specular maps
    vector<Texture> specularMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
    textures.insert(textures.end(), specularMaps.begin(), specularMaps.end());
    // 3. normal maps
    std::vector<Texture> normalMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_HEIGHT, "texture_normal");
    textures.insert(textures.end(), normalMaps.begin(), normalMaps.end());
    // 4. height maps
    std::vector<Texture> heightMaps = loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_AMBIENT, "texture_height");
    textures.insert(textures.end(), heightMaps.begin(), heightMaps.end());

    // return a mesh object created from the extracted mesh data
    return Mesh(nodeName, vertices, indices, textures);
}

vector<Texture> Model::loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* mat, aiTextureType type, string typeName)
{
    vector<Texture> textures;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mat->GetTextureCount(type); i++)
    {
        aiString str;
        mat->GetTexture(type, i, &str);
        bool skip = false;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < textures_loaded.size(); j++)
        {
            if (std::strcmp(textures_loaded[j].path.data(), str.C_Str()) == 0)
            {
                textures.push_back(textures_loaded[j]);
                skip = true; // a texture with the same filepath has already been loaded, continue to next one. (optimization)
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!skip)
        {   // if texture hasn't been loaded already, load it
            Texture texture;
            texture.id = TextureFromFile(str.C_Str(), this->directory);
            texture.type = typeName;
            texture.path = str.C_Str();
            textures.push_back(texture);
            textures_loaded.push_back(texture);  // store it as texture loaded for entire model, to ensure we won't unnecesery load duplicate textures.
        }
    }
    return textures;
}

unsigned int TextureFromFile(const char* path, const string& directory, bool gamma)
{
    string filename = string(path);
    filename = directory + '/' + filename;

    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    return textureID;
}


And this is (part of) what I have inside the main class:
std::string helicopterObjFileName = (currentPath + "\\Models\\Helicopter\\helicopter.dae");
Model helicopterObjModel1(helicopterObjFileName, false);

glm::mat4 mainRotorTransform = glm::mat4(1.0f); // Identity matrix
glm::mat4 rearRotorTransform = glm::mat4(1.0f); // Identity matrix
float angle = 0.0f; // Initial rotation angle

// render loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    // per-frame time logic
    double currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
    deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = currentFrame;

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float intensity = 1.0f;
    // Update rotor angle
    angle += glm::radians(90.0f) * deltaTime * 10; // Rotate 90 degrees 10 times per second

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    glm::vec3 heliPosition1 = glm::vec3(-5.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
    lightingWithTextureShader.setMat4("projection", pCamera->GetProjectionMatrix());
    lightingWithTextureShader.setMat4("view", pCamera->GetViewMatrix());
    glm::mat4 helicopterModel1 = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(1.f));
    helicopterModel1 = glm::translate(helicopterModel1, heliPosition1);;
    helicopterModel1 = glm::rotate(helicopterModel1, glm::radians(90.f), glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));;
    lightingWithTextureShader.setMat4("model", helicopterModel1);

    //This is for moving the node the new position of the model
    mainRotorTransform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), heliPosition1);
    //This is for animating the node so that it's constantly rotating
    mainRotorTransform = glm::rotate(mainRotorTransform, angle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    //This is for rotating the node so that it is one exact same position as the model
    mainRotorTransform = glm::rotate(mainRotorTransform, glm::radians(90.0f), glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    rearRotorTransform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), glm::vec3(-5.0f, 15.0f, 0.0f));
    rearRotorTransform = glm::rotate(rearRotorTransform, rearAngle, glm::vec3(0.0f,  5.0f, 0.0f));
    rearRotorTransform = glm::rotate(rearRotorTransform, glm::radians(90.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));


    
    helicopterObjModel1.setIsAnimated(true);
    helicopterObjModel1.moveModel(helicopterModel1);
    helicopterObjModel1.setNodeTransforms("main_rotor", mainRotorTransform);
    helicopterObjModel.setNodeTransforms("rear_rotor", rearRotorTransform);

    helicopterObjModel1.Draw(lightingWithTextureShader);

For the Model class, I added a new map member named "nodeTransforms" which has string as its key (the name of the node) and mat4 as its mapped value for rotations and transformations.
As you can see, inside the Model class, I wrote the Draw method so that it uses the setMat4 function on every node inside nodeTransforms. I also had to create the moveModel method for models that have isAnimated true because I couldn't use glm::rotate and glm::translate directly on them.
In main, the biggest issue I have is with the rear_rotor node, since it does not rotate around its own center. I tried changing its coordinates around and switching the order of the translate and rotate matrices applied to this node, but this issue still remains. I think the problem is that the rear rotor is rotating around the center of entire helicopter object rather than its own center.
Also, the main motor node works mostly fine, but, right before I started writing this, I noticed that it is a bit off center, as well.
Can anyone help me out? Is there a better way to animate specific nodes in OpenGL?

"the biggest issue I have is with the rear_rotor node" -- This means you should reduce your [mre] to just the rear rotor, displayed in a single color (keep it simple -- no diffuse maps, no specular maps, no normal maps, no height maps; just the bare minimum to make the rotor visible).

Can you attach a screenshot maybe of what is exactly wrong with the rear_rotor node? One of the approaches could be that you define some root transform for your whole model, and then optionally specify additional transformations for each mesh that will be set relative to your model origin.
